# Why is “dark matter” a more parsimonious explanation than “more normal matter than we thought”?

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't dark matter just matter ?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/why-isnt-dark-matter-just-matter)

The evidence usually presented in support of dark matter is larger-than-expected masses in galaxy clusters: the mass required for the gravitational lensing is far larger than the mass detected in the galaxies themselves.

So why, then, is the assumption that this undetected extra mass is **a previously-unknown kind of matter**? Why is that new concept required, instead of proposing that the estimates of total normal matter are wrong?

Another way of asking the same question could be: Why are we **more sure of our estimate of the sum of normal matter** than of the evidence that there is more mass in galaxy clusters than estimated?

Comment: It's a good question (and well written), but it's already been asked. You'll find some answers on the one linked as a duplicate.