# How do trace element abundances show that dark matter exists in both baryonic and non - baryonic forms?

Tags: particle-physics, dark-matter, matter, elements, baryons

I can't seem to find an answer to this question anywhere, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Baryonic_vs._nonbaryonic_matter). I'll formulate it into an answer if it is helpful.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, i had a look but couldn't tell why what was said would indicate that dark matter must be both baryonic and non-baryonic

Comment: "The theory of Big Bang nucleosynthesis predicts the observed abundance of the chemical elements;agreement with observed abundances requires that baryonic matter makes up between 4–5% of the universe's critical density." and "Unlike baryonic matter, nonbaryonic matter did not contribute to the formation of the elements in the early universe ("Big Bang nucleosynthesis") and so its presence is revealed only via its gravitational effects. " and we think some must be non-baryonic because dark matter "is not accounted for by dark energy, baryonic matter (ordinary matter), and neutrinos."

Comment: Have a look at [Why can't dark matter be baryonic?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153722/why-cant-dark-matter-be-baryonic/153737#153737)

Comment: I believe dark matter is thought to be non-baryonic, and the amount of baryonic (normal) matter in the universe is enough to account for the amount of elements in the big bang (see quote in comment above).