Can cosmic objects made of "frozen" nobel elements be mistaken for "Dark Matter"?
Could a large solid object made of a nobel element give a false reading of a remote galaxy's mass like Dark Matter does?
AI chat bots say "In many ways, yes".
I am not sure. Dark Matter is undefined...just it's undetectability and it's affect on gravity.

How would this hypothesis differ from asking whether dark matter could be cold white dwarfs or lost golf balls (which has been answered several times on Physics SE). Why would it need to be Argon or Neon? e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/why-isnt-dark-matter-just-ordinary-matter

Dark matter does not interact with EM radiation (light, microwaves, infrared -- nothing). Boring everyday matter, including noble gases, do interact with EM radiation.

Furthermore, relying on an AI chatbot to convey ideas in physics is not a way to learn physics. They work on language models and have no understanding of the underlying physics itself
